# Create a button that reruns JavaScript for canvas

Tags: javascript, canvas

I basically would like to create a button that execute the function every time when i click on it, like this example http://billmill.org/static/canvastutorial/move.html here if you click on "run code" button, the function is executed from beginning, but when i tried to use "onclick" or "evenlistener", my function won't restart, instead it speed up and not rerun from the center, and i have to refresh my page.

here is an example i have tried, didn't work out well, pls help!

```
<input type="button" value="click" id="clickme">
```

and script, `init()` is just a function for canvas

```
var btn = document.getElementById("clickme");

btn.addEventListener("click", function() {
init(); 
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is because inside the `init` function `setInterval` is being called which calls the `draw` function every 10ms, so if you click the button multiple times, you will be setting multiple intervals that all call the `draw` function without resetting any of the intervals. `x` and `y` are increased in `draw`, so the animation will speed up if `draw` is called more often. If you want the animation to reset on `init`, you must reset the values of x and y and clear the existing interval.

Like this:

```
var x = 150;
var y = 150;
var dx = 2;
var dy = 4;
var intervalId;
var ctx;

function init() { 
  ctx = $('#canvas')[0].getContext("2d");
  if(intervalId) {
    clearInterval(intervalId);
    x = 150;
    y = 150;
  } 
  intervalId = setInterval(draw, 10);
  return intervalId;
}

function draw() {
  ctx.clearRect(0,0,300,300);
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.arc(x, y, 10, 0, Math.PI*2, true); 
  ctx.closePath();
  ctx.fill();
  x += dx;
  y += dy;
}

init();
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: thanks a bunch! didn't understand first but your answer gave me an idea and solved the problem! really appreciated!